# Adding group bar charts as subplots in plotly

Tags: python, charts, plotly

I want to create grouped (**barmode='group'**) bar chart subplots in plotly. Now the problem is that plotly doesn't create bar charts as traces. Instead grouped bar charts are created as lists of Bar traces. Because of this, I don't know how to create a figure that contains grouped bar charts as subplots (i.e. add a grouped bar chart using **figure.append_trace()**).

For example, how can I create subplots using bar charts created in [this sample](https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/#grouped-bar-chart):

```py
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    y=[20, 14, 23],
    name='SF Zoo'
)
trace2 = go.Bar(
    x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    y=[12, 18, 29],
    name='LA Zoo'
)
data = [trace1, trace2]
layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='group'
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot_url = py.plot(fig, filename='grouped-bar')
```

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: Would you be open to solutions using matplotlib instead of plotly?

Comment: @hobenkr yes that would be fine

Comment: Any solutions in plotly?  I'm constrained due to embed integration issues.

Answer (score 13):

YES!  New to plot.ly and had this issue, and as mentioned in my comment, I couldn't just do it in pandas/matplotlib for various reasons.  But through the magic of subplots, you can in fact recreate multi-trace plots by just subploting them together.
[image]

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import tools

trace1 = Bar(
    x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    y=[20, 14, 23],
    name='SF Zoo'
)
trace2 = Bar(
    x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    y=[12, 18, 29],
    name='LA Zoo'
)
trace3 = Scatter(
  x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']
  ,y=[33,20,17]
  ,name='subplots ftw'
  )


fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True)

fig.append_trace(trace3, 1,1)
fig.append_trace(trace1, 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2,2,1)


fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=600)
iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Would have never figured that out myself!

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the plotly package but what it seems you are after is fairly straightforward using matplotlib. Here is a pretty minimal example of showing grouped bar charts as a subplot. Let me know if this is not quite what you were asking for.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# First subplot
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)

x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = np.sin(np.pi * x)

plt.plot(x, y)

# Second subplot
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
titles = ('Canada', 'US', 'England', 'Other')
y_pos = np.arange(len(titles))
width = 0.2
bar_height1 = [6,5,7,2]
bar_height2 = [x+1 for x in bar_height1]

plt.bar(y_pos, bar_height1, width, align='center', alpha=0.8, color='r')
plt.bar(y_pos+width, bar_height2, width, align='center', alpha=0.8, color='b')

plt.xticks(y_pos + width/2, titles)

# Show the plots
plt.show()
```

[image: Matplotlib plot]